# Send Footer To the End of The Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I send my footer towards the bottom of my screen and how can I extend it to the full screen in a responsive way?
[image]

Footer.css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: black;
}

.text{
  color: white;
}
```

Footer.tsx:

```
const Footer = () => (
  <footer className="site-footer">
  <p className = 'text'>  APP</p>
</footer>
  );

  export default Footer;
```

Comment: you need to make it position fixed, and set it's bottom to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution:

```
<style>

   .site-footer{
      position: fixed; left:0; bottom:0; width: 100%;
   }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
.site-footer{
       left: 0;
       bottom : 0;
       background: #000;
       position: fixed;
       display: block;
    }
```

Also, If you don't want it to be fixed, just use this:

```
.site-footer {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: left:0 is also required.